# Looking for an alternative testing software

Tags: automated-testing, visualstudio, mtm, tfs

A few years ago we converted from Excel spreadsheets to TFS 2013. MTM (Microsoft Test Manager) was bundled at the time and had out of the box compatibility with TFS. Recently we have been looking at moving to automation and are running into a few snags. Management is no longer satisfied with the defect traceability of MTM, and testers are not able to easily implement automated scripts.

I was hoping you all would be able to recommend some testing software that meets the below qualifications:

- Ability to run both manual and automated scripts.
- Connect to TFS 2013 for linking requirements, defects, test cases, user stories, etc.
- Be able to nest test cases.
- Create test run summaries that can then be sent to customers.
- Must be able to run both web and local applications.

There are other features that are important to the company, but the above fit our immediate needs.

I have been tasked with comparing alternative testing tools, but it seems like very few programs are compatible with TFS. What software does your company use to connect with TFS? How does it suit your companies immediate needs?

Comment: You may not find an exact match, but Jenkins is a popular option and very well supported tool. It has lots of plug-ins that you may need.

Comment: @YuZhang: jenkins isn't a test framework, it is a continuous integration tool. It can be _part_ of a testing framework but it is not itself a testing framework.

Answer (score 1):

My company currently uses the Atlassian toolset (Jira, Confluence, etc).

It integrates well and allows tracking of work items well.

If you combine this with the various plugins, then this will give you a strong system for tracking the things customers are typically interested in.

Looking at Test Management specifically, I would go for TestRail over Zephyr.

TestRail has greater functionality, easy access to reporting tools and the ability to group tests.

Answer (score 0):

I agree - I don't think there is an exact match with your requirements but I found a combination of Jenkins (or any CI build server) for build and automated tests and Jira for everything else works well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Visual studio that connects with TFS and also matches your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

(I'm not able to add a comment to the original question probably because of my low reputation score so I'm adding this as a top level answer. Feel free to delete if this violates some posting rules.)

To solve the problem of "testers are not able to easily implement automated tests," I wrote a wrapper around Cucumber/Selenium which makes is trivially easy to write and run automated tests.

My framework: http://kheera.in

Hope this is of use to someone. We are seeing good results with it at a client.